# What is the time complexity of string.GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, big-o, time-complexity, hashcode

What is the time complexity of the method `String.GetHashCode()`? For example, if hashed string of length `n`, by `mod 2` using Horner's scheme it's `O(n)`.
What is Big O for GetHashCode?

Comment: I don't think it's specified, which means "you should not make any assumptions". If you want this information to do something then you are going down the wrong path. If you ask out of curiosity, why not just use a decompiler and find out?

Comment: If to clarify question, I would like to know how working this method, if it provides an advantage in performance over a method with Horner's scheme.

Comment: Well, technically is O(n/4), but I believe that is considered O(n).  String.GetHashCode generates a hash of the memory used by the string based on the words (two at a time), not the characters (hence n/4)

Comment: If you want to change the way String.GetHashCode works (and potentially reduce hash collisions, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152924(v=vs.110).aspx I don't know the Big-O of the randomized algorithm.

Comment: Should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053726/why-might-a-system-string-object-not-cache-its-hash-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#0a17bbac4851d0d4) the time complexity is O(n). It basically just takes each character of the string and adds its value to the hash.

As mentioned in [Peter Ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620/peter-ritchie)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939407/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-string-gethashcode#comment40609741_25939407) the algorithm can be changed by using the [`<UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/userandomizedstringhashalgorithm-element).